# MKStoreKit 4.0: How to check if an auto-renewable subscription has been renewed?

Tags: ios, subscription, storekit, renewal

I'm using MKStoreKit 4.0 to implement auto-renewable subscriptions in my app and I am able to purchase subscriptions fine but can't get auto-renewal to be successfully tested. This is what I'm doing:

- I initialize MKStoreManager at the start of the app.
- Whenever the the user is about to access a feature that requires a subscription I call the `isSubscriptionActive:` method for the corresponding subscription type.

My questions are:

1) Is this a valid way to use MKStoreKit for auto-renewables? (If not how should I do it?)
2) Has anyone successfully used auto-renewable subscriptions with MKSToreKit and if so how?

Thanks in advance for any help.

P.S. - I've thought of using restore purchases but that would require a password authentication from the user and showing that every time the app checks for subscription status would defeat the purpose of auto-renewable subscriptions.

Comment: Can you please send me code how you have implemented MKStoreKit in your code... Thanks in advance... You can send me it on my email id nilesh08.ec@gmail.com

Comment: I ended up using ASTStoreKit instead after running into a couple of issues with MKStoreKit.

Comment: Do you still have your code for the MKStoreKit?  I would be very interested in how you implemented it. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I removed it entirely from the project and while it's probably still in a revision somewhere in the SVN repository I have no idea how stable or effective that code would be.

Comment: Just in case anyone else posts a comment asking for my code the answer is: sorry I don't have any good implementation to offer but I would really consider ASTStoreKit as an alternative. It's slightly more complicated to set up but at least I found that it was much easier to read the code for it and make sense of the library. Also the support in my experience is better.